# Removed nested array php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array which is

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [city_id] => 16
            [city_name] => San Diego
            [state_abbreviation] => CA
            [city_lat] => 32.715328
            [city_long] => -117.157257
            [city_image] => sandiego_ca.jpg
        )

)
```

i just want to show

```
 Array
            (
                [city_id] => 16
                [city_name] => San Diego
                [state_abbreviation] => CA
                [city_lat] => 32.715328
                [city_long] => -117.157257
                [city_image] => sandiego_ca.jpg
            )
```

Basically removing the [0] nest so i could parse it better

Comment: `$array = $array[0]; print_r($array);` but if you show us how you get your first array there might be a better way to achieve the same.

Comment: Why and how would just using `[0]` be problematic? Share specific code samples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not php array can do like this . just use a tmp variable.

$arr = $this_arr[0];

That's it .